# How should be installed XAMPP and Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Tags: php, sql-server, configuration, xampp, wamp

My aim is getting an Apache-Microsoft SQL server 2014- PHP configuration in a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 environment

I have a vm Microsoft Windows server 2008 R2 (64bit), with SQL Server 2014 management Studio installed  (80 port) that i would like not remove.

I think i have 3 options:

1. XAMPP and SQL Server 2014
2. WAMP and SQL Server 2014
3. Separate installation of Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6

I prefere the most easy way.
I tried with no success the second and the third points.

Below my last attempt:

After that, i installed XAMPP.
i installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable 11.06 because during the installation i was alerted for a missing dll.

After that i remove and reinstalled XAMPP but in the panel controll when i star the Apache service i was alerted that 80 port was occupied by SQL Server so i change Apache port both httpd.conf (listen 8079) and in panel control XAMPP service settings.

I disinstalled and reinstalled XAMPP and i got:

```
status change detected: running
```

but with Firefox 43 browser at localhost address i got a white page.
if i open the file index.php from the

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

i got the generic error:

```
something is wrong with the xampp installation :-(
```

If i start also Mysql service nothing gonna change.
Mercury Filezilla and tomcat are stopped.

I tried also WAMP but i got the same white page.
Usually without SQL Server i have always installed easily WAMP and XAMPP!

Thank you

Comment: why would you have sqlserver listening on port 80 in the first place? why not the usual default 1433?

Comment: I do not know, i wrote what XAMPP told me. they gave me the vm with SQL Server installed. How can i change it?